# How to make an indented UITableViewCell with rounded corners and single line borders

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to build a UITableView with cells that have rounded corners, borders and are indented. With these three combined, I have difficulty getting a 1.0pt border on the sides and between in the cells for each case (1 cell, 2 cells, > 2 cells).

In the simplest version, the only problem is that the borders between the cells are double width. Since the `borderWidth` can only be set for the entire frame, I've tried to add individual borders with this:

```
extension CALayer {
    func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {
        let border = CALayer()
        switch edge {
        case .top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
        case .bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - thickness, width: frame.width, height: thickness)
        case .left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
        case .right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)
        default:
            break
        }

        border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;
        addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

When adding the borders individually with the `addBorder` approach, other problem occur like:

- The border on the right side isn't visible because the new frame width that is set for the indention isn't taken into account
- The corners aren't rounded correctly
- There's still a double width separator

Moreover, the type of problem also depends on whether the view is directly loaded (after re-running the app) or after adding / removing a cell.

`clipToBounds` is set to true in the IB and the ContentMode of the ContentView is set to center.

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` as follows:

```
enum RoundedTableViewCellType {
    case first
    case last
    case single
    case middle
}

class RoundedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            let inset: CGFloat = 20
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += inset
            frame.size.width -= 2 * inset
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }

    var type: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle {
        didSet {
            switch type {
            case .first:
                layer.cornerRadius = 6
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .last:
                layer.cornerRadius = 6
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            case .single:
                layer.cornerRadius = 6
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .middle:
                layer.cornerRadius = 0
                layer.maskedCorners = []
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.primaryTransparant.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
}
```

To clarify:

**desired result**

[image]

**actual result**

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Only **There's still a double width separator** this issue I am seeing and rest of two points look fine..

Comment: Right, the other issues only occur when adding borders per side with `addBorder`, which I did not do in the example because I'm not sure if that's the right direction to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.borderColor` `.borderWidth` and `.cornerRadius` on the table view's layer, instead of cells?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work because the the tableView has the same width as the screen, the inset is done by overriding the `frame` property in `RoundedTableViewCell`.

Comment: @bas-d - I really think changing the size of your table view is the easiest route, but if you must take the approach of overriding the `frame` to give it insets, see my edited answer for another way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a typical `UITableView`, this was achieved:

[image]

by adding these lines in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    myTableView.layer.borderColor = myTableView.separatorColor?.cgColor
    myTableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    myTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
```

---

**Edit:** Another approach, accommodating the use of `frame` override to give the table "insets".

Add a `CAShapeLayer` as a sub-layer to the cell. Set its path to a `UIBezierPath` that forms the correct edges and corners.

Top cell will have only left, top and right edges (no bottom), with top corners rounded.

Middle cells will have left, top and right edges (no bottom), with NO corners rounded.

Bottom cell will have all 4 edges, with bottom corners rounded.

A cell in a one-row table will have all 4 edges, with all 4 corners rounded.

Result:

[image]

Complete code (no IBOutlets needed):

```
enum RoundedTableViewCellType {
    case first
    case last
    case single
    case middle
}

class RoundedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .bold)
        v.textColor = UIColor(red: 62.0 / 255.0, green: 43.0 / 255.0, blue: 191.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()

    private var borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var myType: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            let inset: CGFloat = 20
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += inset
            frame.size.width -= 2 * inset
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }

    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    // need to re-set layer cornerRadius if radius is set *after* type (in VC's cellForRowAt)
    var radius: CGFloat = 6.0 {
        didSet {
            type = myType
        }
    }

    var type: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle {
        didSet {
            myType = type
            switch type {
            case .first:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .last:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            case .single:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .middle:
                layer.cornerRadius = 0
                layer.maskedCorners = []
            }
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let r = radius
        var bPath = UIBezierPath()

        let ptTopLeft  = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        let ptTopRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0.0)
        let ptBotRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height)
        let ptBotLeft  = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: bounds.height)

        switch type {
        case .first:
            // top cell, add left, top and right edges
            // round top corners
            bPath.move(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x, y: ptTopLeft.y + r))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x + r, y: ptTopLeft.y),
                               controlPoint: ptTopLeft)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x - r, y: ptTopRight.y))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x, y: ptTopRight.y + r),
                               controlPoint: ptTopRight)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotRight.x, y: ptBotRight.y))

        case .last:
            // bottom cell, add all four edges
            // round bottom corners
            bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                 byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                 cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))

        case .single:
            // one-row table, add all four edges
            // round all four corners
            bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: r)

        case .middle:
            // middle cell, add left, top, right edges
            // round NO corners
            bPath.move(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptTopLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptTopRight)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptBotRight)

        }

        borderLayer.path = bPath.cgPath

    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            ])

        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        // default values
        borderColor = UIColor(red: 220.0 / 255.0, green: 215.0 / 255.0, blue: 244.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        borderWidth = 1.0

    }

}

class RoundedCornersInsetTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var myTableView: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var theData = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242.0 / 255.0, green: 240.0 / 255.0, blue: 250.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self

        myTableView.register(RoundedTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "RoundedTableViewCell")

        myTableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        myTableView.separatorStyle = .none

        myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        view.addSubview(myTableView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain top + 40-pts
            myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),

            // constrain leading / trailing to 0.0
            myTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // change this as appropriate
            myTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400.0)

            ])
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RoundedTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RoundedTableViewCell
        cell.theLabel.text = "Cell \(theData[indexPath.row])"
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        if theData.count == 1 {

            cell.type = .single

        } else {

            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                cell.type = .first
            } else if indexPath.row == theData.count - 1 {
                cell.type = .last
            } else {
                cell.type = .middle
            }

        }

        // configurable cell border properties
        //cell.borderColor = UIColor(red: 220.0 / 255.0, green: 215.0 / 255.0, blue: 244.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        //cell.borderWidth = 2.0
        //cell.radius = 16.0

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Issue is with border when setting border to 1 pixel frame takes 1 pixel from all four sides for first cell and when it creates second cell it again takes 1 pixel from all four sides Now on top border of 2nd cell combine with bottom border of 1st cell which actually appears like 2 pixel of thickness you need to handle this.

```
    extension UIView {
// Example use: myView.addBorder(toSide: .Left, withColor: UIColor.redColor().CGColor, andThickness: 1.0)

enum ViewSide {
case Left, Right, Top, Bottom
    }
func addBorder(toSide side: ViewSide, withColor color: CGColor, andThickness thickness: CGFloat) {
let border = CALayer()
        border.backgroundColor = color
switch side {
case .Left: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: thickness, height: frame.height); break
case .Right: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.maxX, y: frame.minY, width: thickness, height: frame.height); break
case .Top: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: thickness); break
case .Bottom: border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.maxY, width: frame.width, height: thickness); break
        }
        layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
}
```

1- For first cell add border drop all sides

2- and for others add borders except Top border.

Comment: I know the reason, but just don't know how to fix it correctly.